# Binding a checkbox in Angularjs in Directive

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

I have a plunk at http://plnkr.co/PF7cRQE4n5lYube8oa3t

The templateUrl points to control.html with the following code.

```
hello from Directive
<br />{{message}}
<br />
<input type="checkbox" {{checkedstatus}} />
<br />Value of Checked Status = {{checkedstatus}}
```

My controller and directive is as follows...

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
})
  .directive('myDir', function() {
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attributes){
      scope.message = "The check box should be checked... no?";
      scope.checkedstatus = "checked";
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: "control.html",
      link: linkFunction,
      scope: {}
    };
  })
```

My index.html file is straight forward and is using the directive...

```
<my-dir></my-dir>
```

I was assuming that if checkedstatus is set to "checked" I will see the checkbox as checked in the UI. But it doesn't happen that way and remains unchecked. My goal is to use this Checkbox as a toggle button to view or hide certain elements of my view.

Comment: Try using this pattern > http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ng-checked`

```
scope.checkbox={
    checkedstatus:true
};

<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkbox.checkedstatus" />
```

Or you can bind model

like this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox.checkedstatus" />
```

Check on plunkr

> http://plnkr.co/edit/qkWyqrLBwYKv1ECZ0WHE?p=preview

Comment: I have attached the link of plunkr